# React doesn't fetch notes on first login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have made a note taking react app using MERN stack with react router dom v6. When I first visit the website I am redirected to the login page which is correct. When I log in the page rerenders but it is not rediredted to the home page. Although this behaviour happens only the first time I log in after opening the page. If I log out and log in again everything works as expected and I am redirected to the homepage.

I am using JWT for auth.

[Link to github repo](https://github.com/debarkamondal/dezire-notebook-frontend)

This is the part of the code that should be responsible for the behaviour.
`/src/pages/LoginPage.jsx`

```
const LoginPage = () => {
  const { setauthToken } = useContext(noteContext);
  const [creds, setCreds] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setCreds({ ...creds, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (
    e,
    url = "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login"
  ) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: creds.email, password: creds.password }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();

    // After submiting creds checking the response from the server
    if ("authToken" in json) {
      setauthToken(json.authToken);
      localStorage.setItem("authToken", json.authToken);
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    } else console.log("invalid creds");
    return json;
  };
```

React router setup:

```
import "./App.css";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import NoteState from "./context/notes/NoteState";
import RootLayout from "./pages/RootLayout";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route exact path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <NoteState>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </NoteState>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Code responsible for kicking non logged in session in Note component within homepage:

```
const Notes = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(noteContext);
  const { notes, getNotes } = context;
  const authToken = props.authToken;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    authToken ? getNotes() : navigate("/login");
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
```

Normal behaviour:

- Page redirects to homepage and fetches all the notes.

What is happening:

- After first login redirection to home page not working.
- Everything works fine after first logout.

Comment: Does your app have any logic that will kick back the user to the login page again if it detects that the user isn't logged in? If it does, can you show us that code?

Comment: within the homepage's note component i have built in the logic `useEffect(() => {
    authToken ? getNotes() : navigate("/login");
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);`

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of head scratching my tiny brain gave me the answer.

Actually, I am using auth token as the main factor to redirect people to home screen after login and login screen after log out.

So, after first login user was navigated to `"/"` before auth token was set as context.

Solution:

I fetched the authToken from the local storage directly instead of using context as it takes time to set state variables and also the big problem is that we cant use await with setState.

Instead of using navigate here:

```
if ("authToken" in json) {
      setauthToken(json.authToken);
      localStorage.setItem("authToken", json.authToken);
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    } else console.log("invalid creds");
```

Doing it like this fixed the issue.

```
const authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken");

useEffect(() => {
  authToken ? navigate("/") : navigate("/login");
}, [authToken]);
```